# WordPress MultiSite login to the respective site

Tags: multisite, login

I would like to have one login form (either wp-login.php or custom) that will allow my users to sign in into their respective site.

For instance:

`www.example.com/site1/` <-- URL to the sub site

Now I want to have the login form at `www.example.com` where the user can enter `site1` and their password and logs in to their sub site, redirect to their dashboard directly.

Is this possible? Thanks folks.

Comment: This is how it works already. Are your Mu units separate domains?

Comment: No, I use subdirectory mode on the root domain. Might move to sub-domains in the future.

Comment: You can modify the login form using [various filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=login_form&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook) to add your proposed `site` field. You can filter the destination once the user is logged in using the [`login_redirect` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/). And you can even filter the login URL using the [`login_url` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_url/). So yes, it looks like it's very possible.

Comment: Great resources @PatJ

Comment: Thanks @PatJ for the nudge in the right direction. Now I hope someone writes in a custom function for this to make it easier.

Comment: You might consider [hiring someone](http://jobs.wordpress.net/post-a-job/) to write your custom function, if you're not comfortable writing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But like @prosti said, it is how it works already. Turned out, I just needed to make sure the user is not added to the main site.

Comment: Do you want me to add this answer @HelloWorld?

Comment: Sure @prosti, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is how it works already. 
You can have the user sign in using the main site's wp-login.php.

*In your case just make sure the user is not added to the main site.*